# Linked list in rust, Needed optimization

Tags: linked-list, reinventing-the-wheel, rust

I've implemented constructor, push , pop, drop and some macro.

I need to know if the drop implementation is correct and is drop is really necessary?

Meanwhile I still didn't check about `std::rc::Rc` and lifetime implementations.

```rust
use std::mem;
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
pub struct LinkedList<T> {
    head: Option<Box<Node<T>>>,
}

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Clone)]
struct Node<T> {
    value:  T,
    next: Option<Box<Node<T>>>,
}

impl<T> LinkedList<T> {
    pub fn new() -> LinkedList<T> {
   
        let new: LinkedList<T> = LinkedList {
            head: None,
        };
        new
    }
    pub fn push(&mut self, value: T) {
        let new_tail: Node<T> = Node { value, next: None };
        let mut ptr = &mut self.head;
        loop {
            match ptr {
                None => {
                    *ptr = Some(Box::new(new_tail));
                    break;
                }
                Some(node) => {
                    ptr = &mut node.next;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    pub fn pop(&mut self) -> Option<T>
    where
        T: Copy,
    {
        let mut ptr = &mut self.head;
        loop {
            match ptr {
                None => {
                    return None;
                }
                Some(node) if node.next.is_none() => {
                    let val = node.value;
                    *ptr = None;
                    return Some(val);
                }
                Some(node) => {
                    ptr = &mut node.next;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    pub fn drop(&mut self) {
        let mut ptr=mem::replace(&mut self.head, None);
        while let Some(mut node) = ptr {
            ptr=mem::replace(&mut node.next, None);
        }
    }
    pub fn get_tail(&mut self)->  Option<&mut Node<T>>{

        let mut ptr=&mut self.head;
        loop {
            
    
        match ptr.as_mut() {
            None=>{
               return None;
            },
            Some(node) if(node.next.is_none()) =>{
                return Some(node)
              
            },
            Some(node) =>{
              ptr=&mut node.next;
            }
        }
    }
       
    }
}
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! linkedlist {
    ( $( $x:expr ),* ) => {
        {
            let mut temp_vec = LinkedList::new();
            $(
                temp_vec.push($x);
            )*
            temp_vec
        }
    };
}
#[cfg(test)]
mod test {
    use super::*;
    #[test]
    fn create_test() {
        let new_linked_list: LinkedList<i32> = LinkedList::new();
        println!("{:?}", new_linked_list);
    }
    #[test]
    fn push() {
        let mut new_linked_list: LinkedList<i32> = LinkedList::new();
        new_linked_list.push(1);
        new_linked_list.push(2);
        new_linked_list.push(3);
        println!(" push {:?}", new_linked_list);
        let popped = new_linked_list.pop();
        println!("popped {:?} ", popped);
        println!("array {:?}", new_linked_list);
    }
    #[test]
    fn get_tail(){
         let mut new_linked_list: LinkedList<i32> = LinkedList::new();
        new_linked_list.push(1);
        new_linked_list.push(2);
        new_linked_list.push(3);
        println!("{:?}",new_linked_list.get_tail());
    }
    #[test]
    fn macro_test() {
        let ll=linkedlist!(5,6,7,8);
        println!("{:?}",ll);
    }
}
```

I just did this on a Sunday afternoon, and I'm surprised this even works. Hence, I need to know how can I better implement and optimize this code. Does my code cause any issues?

Comment: You could simplify this code by having only the node type. A separate type for the list would make sense if you made it a doubly-linked list (with weak references backwards).

Answer (score 3):

The code already looks pretty good. Nonetheless here are some issues I have with it:

The code as given does not compile on my system. To compile a binary, there's a `main()` function missing.
To compile a library, you have to make `Node` public, since you return it from a public function of a public struct.

This

```rust
    pub fn new() -> LinkedList<T> {
   
        let new: LinkedList<T> = LinkedList {
            head: None,
        };
        new
    }
```

can be written as

```rust
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            head: None,
        }
    }
```

This way, you don't need to repeat the name of the struct in the return type and constructor call and you can also spare a local variable.

Also consider running `rustfmt` on your sources, so that your code has the recommended formatting to be easier to read for other Rust developers.

If I understand it correctly, the `drop()` function should free the memory of the `LinkedList`. This is not necessary, since all members of the involved structures use [managed memory already](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/std/box.html).
So just dropping the [owner](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/obrm.html) of the `LinkedList` out of scope will free all related memory automatically.